# Is there a way to simultaneously delete an email and move to the next with Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gmail

I use the <kbd>#</kbd> key to delete emails in Gmail, but then I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get into the next conversation (Gmail automatically redirects to the inbox I was in previously).

This is probably pedantic and wishing for it means I deserve a medal for lethargy, but is there a way I can just hit <kbd>#</kbd> and the next email shows up (I think this is the way Yahoo mail works)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make Gmail automatically open the next (or previous) message instead of going back to the message list:

*Note: The new google doesn't have the option under the general tab anymore*

- Select *Settings* in Gmail.
- Go to the [*Labs*](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/labs) tab.
- Make sure *Enable* is selected for *Auto-advance*.
- Click *Save Changes*.

[Source](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Have-Gmail-Open-The-Next-Message-Automatically-When-You-Delete-Or-Archive.htm).

Comment: Amazing - I know Stackexchange doesn't like 'thank you' replies - but this answer deserves it. Thank you so much, that's _perfectly_ what I need.

Comment: ok.. enjoy Mr. @adityamenon